# как сделать так чтобы знаки (+, -, *, /) были в рандомном порядке. в JS

Tags: javascript

как сделать так чтобы знаки (+, -, *, /) были в рандомном порядке в JS. то есть если  я с помощью alert хочу 5 раз сгенерировать знаки (с помощью функции)

по типу такого:

```
function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}
```

но чтобы это были не цифры а знаки

Comment: `'+-*/'[rand(0, 4)]`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const rand = (min, max)  => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;

const vocabulary = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];

let str = '';
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
  str += vocabulary[rand(0, vocabulary.length-1)];
}
console.log(str);
```